# remove redundant ticker in x-axis shared plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I just tried to draw a x-axis shared plot. But there is a redundant axis (0 and 1 on the edge of the plot)in the y axis. How can I get rid of this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
plt.figure()
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(8, 4)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.65, hspace=0)
axF = plt.subplot(gs1[0, :])
axE = plt.subplot(gs1[1, :],sharex=axF)
axPA = plt.subplot(gs1[2, :],sharex=axF)
axMiu = plt.subplot(gs1[3:7, :],sharex=axF)
axRes = plt.subplot(gs1[7, :],sharex=axF)
```

Sorry that I'm not able to post the image. As you can see on the result image, there are some overlapped or redundant axis values on the left or right of y axis.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the yaxis.set_ticks function to define what ticks you want

For example :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(8, 4)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.65, hspace=0)

plot=[]

axF = plt.subplot(gs1[0, :])
plot.append(axF)

axE = plt.subplot(gs1[1, :],sharex=axF)
plot.append(axE)

axPA = plt.subplot(gs1[2, :],sharex=axF)
plot.append(axPA)

axMiu = plt.subplot(gs1[3:7, :],sharex=axF)
plot.append(axMiu)

axRes = plt.subplot(gs1[7, :],sharex=axF)
plot.append(axRes)

for plot_selected in plot:
    plot_selected.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0.2,1.1,0.2))
    plot_selected.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0.2,1.1,0.2))

plot_selected.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.2))



plt.show()
```

Gives the following plot :

[image: plot_example]